# whatsapp error al enviar pdf, "Fallo al compartir"

Tags: android, whatsapp

Tengo una app propia que envia un pdf al whatsapp, lo hacia todo bien, pero desde hace un tiempo el whatsapp (solo en esta app) me dice "Fallo al compartir ......" y no lo puedo enviar. He actualizado la app y el gradle pero nada de nada.

La App funciona bien porque llega a la conversacion de la persoan en cuestion en el whatsapp y solo al darle en el ultimo boton de enviar en el whatsapp es cuando sale este error.

El pdf que genera se graba en un directorio del telefono y se puede enviar por whatsapp si lo hacer desde whatsapp como se hace habitualmente.

He actualizado todas las app y tanto el whatsapp como esta app les he borrado la cache, pero nada sigue igual.

¿Que esta sucediendo? ¿Como lo puedo arreglar?

Gracias.

---

El codigo es :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                //intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.setType("application/pdf");
                intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                String numTelefono = "34" + gmtelefonos;
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(nombre_completo));
                intent.putExtra("jid", numTelefono + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //numero telefonico sin prefijo "+"!
                startActivity(intent);
```

Lo he intentado tanto con intent.setType("text/plain"); como con                 intent.setType("application/pdf")

Importante: lo he realizado en un Xiaomi versión MIUI 11.0.2.0(QFLEUXM) y versión de Android 10 QKQ y me ha funcionado. Pero en otro Xiaomi versión MIUI 12.5.1.0 y versión Android 11, no me ha funcionado y sale el error de fallo al compartir en el whatsapp. En un Sansung con version Android 11 tambien funciona, por lo cual debe de ser mi whatsapp, pero ya lo he desistaloado y vuelto a instalar y sigue sin funcionat. La app no debe de ser porque funciona en otros telefono.

Comment: Hola! Te recomiendo que adjuntes capturas del error y/o partes del código en las que pienses que tienes el error para que podamos analizarlo, ya que sin él pueden ser muchas cosas lo que estén ocasionando ese problema y no te podremos ofrecer ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que arroja el LogCat? pon tu código dentro de unt `try/catch` y sabremos cuál es el error

Answer (score 0):

Con este bloque de codigo logré hacerlo funcionar en Android 11 en adelante.

```
val b: Bitmap = getBitmapFromView(comprobanteLayout)
        val share = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        share.type = "image/jpeg"
        val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes)
        val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
            contentResolver,
            b, "Title", null
        )
        val imageUri = Uri.parse(path)
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri)
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"))
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).